# Determine if the class that will be created is a children of another

Tags: actionscript-3

For this example, I will use 2 classes, Entity and CSpawner. CSpawner is a children of Entity.

I want to perform the following condition:

```
if((new CSpawner()) is Entity)
```

It works just like intended.

But I want to do this test, without creating a new CSpawner object, something like this:

```
if(CSpawner is Entity)
```

But it doesn't work, because CSpawner is a Class.

How do I perform that kind of conditional without creating a new CSpawner object?

Comment: What do you mean "children"? Do you mean subclass? or an object within the class?

Comment: Why do you need to check if CSpawner is an Entity? Are you planning to edit which class CSpawner extends to some other class besides Entity before compiling? I ask this because if CSpawner extends Entity at compile time, it will always extend Entity so the check seems unnecessary.

Comment: @Jordan No, I wanna make sure that it is the type I want to put a lot of classes in a vector, but I want to throw an error if another developer tries to add a class that is not an entity

Comment: So you have a Vector with objects typed as Class. What are you going to do with that vector?

Comment: @Jordan Maps for my game can create entities using the numerical id of these classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedSuperclassName() is what you are looking for.
It returns the Super class name
You can check the other methods from the utils package - this is ActionScript's basic reflection :)

Comment: Well, it works, but what if CSpawner is a children of another class that is a children of Entity?

Comment: You can go a while cycle, check for Entity until you get to Object :)

Comment: Seems slow, but it's the fastest one here, so I'm gonna accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the describeType() function found under the flash.util package. It provides the kind of data you're looking for (both for instance objects and class objects).

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#describeType()

Comment: +1, but it generates a XML object and I need to loop through it to find if it extends the class I want, it seems pretty slow, I need a solution that doesn't cost so much performance.

Comment: Take a look at the flash.util package. If there's any other solution, it relies on the methods/classes found there. As far as I can tell, there isn't any faster alternative to a solution that uses describeType, but I simply cannot invest more time to find out. Good luck.